# React aws-sdk "ConfigError: Missing region in config" after setting region DynamoDB

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js

I have set the region in the AWS.config at the start of my code. I confirmed it was set properly before calling the DocClient.scan function. However, on running the code, I get an error that the region is missing in the config.

[region:'us-east-1' ---- ConfigError: Missing region in config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX3h8.png)

index.js

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'

const configuration = {
    region: 'us-east-1',
    secretAccessKey: 'SECRETKEYHERE',
    accessKeyId: 'KEYIDHERE'
}

AWS.config.update(configuration)
```

AwsFunctions.js

```
import * as AWS from 'aws-sdk'

const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

export const scanTable = async (tableName) => {
    const params = {
        TableName: tableName,
    };

    console.log(AWS.config);

    const scanResults = [];
    var items;
    do{
        items = await docClient.scan(params).promise();
        items.Items.forEach((item) => scanResults.push(item));
        params.ExclusiveStartKey = items.LastEvaluatedKey;
    }while(typeof items.LastEvaluatedKey !== "undefined");
    
    return scanResults;

};

export const putData = (tableName , data) => {
    var params = {
        TableName: tableName,
        Item: data
    }
    
    docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err)
        } else {
            console.log('Success', data)
        }
    })
}
```